# End session when website is left

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to create a website where you will remain logged in via a session in php as long as you stay in the website but will be logged off if you leave the website.  Example, you would remain logged in when moving from mysite.com/index.php to mysite.com/otherpage.php but would be logged off when you move to othersite.com.  Is this possible?

So far I have tried using ajax and jquery to end the session when the page is left but this also ends the session when the page is refreshed.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'logout.php',
            async:false,
            data: {key_leave:"289583002"}
        });
    });
```

Comment: You could add that ajax call into a jQuery "click" handler only for all external links on your site (perhaps add a css class "external").  When the user clicks off to a different site, they will first be logged out of yours.

Comment: Add a heartbeat that regularly hits your server as long as the user is on the web page, then if one or two of those heartbeats are missed, assume they've left your site and end the session. Doing it on external links won't be effective because not everyone uses a single tab per website. For example, i may have three different areas of your site open at once in three different tabs. If i leave one of them and am still on the others, being automatically logged out would be an inconvenience.

Comment: Generally this is done using sessions or cookies with a set duration that get reset on each heartbeat, that way if a heartbeat doesn't happen for the set duration, the session or cookie is lost, thus causing the user to be logged out.

Comment: @KevinB The concept is you're logged in until you click an external site link.  Having multiple tabs open wouldn't affect that in the slightest...  In fact, clicking on the external link in one tab would log you out of all other tabs, which follows precisely with what the poster requested.

Comment: the point i'm making is it isn't very user friendly to do it that way. yes, you can do it that way, and it would fullfill exactly what he's asking for. But i don't think he's seeing what the side effects of that really are.

Comment: @quasivivo I did not specify but in a scenario like KevinB pointed out where multiple tabs are open I would like the session to remain until all the tabs on that website are closed. Kevin, the heartbeat seems a little brute force but would technically work.

Comment: Heartbeat or on-demand, the webmaster is closing the session.  With a heartbeat, the user returns to the site to find his session has been closed (with an appropriate message explaining why, hopefully).  With a click handler, the user could either be told immediately that his session will be closed by navigating off site or (the same as with the heartbeat) told that his session was closed when he returns.  Neither is ideal (and logging out this way is inherently not user friendly), but at least the user is immediately told about it (and why) with a click handler.

Comment: My biggest concern with the click handler is that if the user manually leaves the page by typing a new address then the session will not be ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to detect whether user left your site (imagine scenario when user just disconnects from internet, but browser is still open, or close browser via KILL), so basically you cannot do what you want.

Anyway here is some clues:

1. Why do you need it at all? What is the goal? Try to re-think your architecture.
2. You can configure session.cookie_lifetime to 0, this will mean "until browser is closed"
3. You can add some javascript "ping" on each page, which will call your script every 10 seconds for example, or stop calling when internet is down, user went to another site and no pages are in other tabs, then you will need separate cron job which will destroy sessions for users without pings last time

Comment: I have rethought my goal and come to the conclusion that this really isn't a requirment.  Thank you everyone for the ideas, this is still a interesting scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple solution is

a) On the server side - If a session exists then retrieve from the database (on the server) the last time the user accessed a page. If too long ago get them to log in again. Otherwise deliver the page and undate the database
b) For a better user experience use Javascript to update the page (setTimeout).

If (b) does not work (i.e. for whatever reason) then at least the server is protected along with the individuals data